# Installing Realm hangs (or takes extremely lot of time)

Tags: ios, realm, mongodb-realm

I'm trying `pod install` to install the Realm (10.8.1) pod.
And it seems to hang completely. I've tried `pod install --verbose`, I deintegrated the pods from the project - and the process really doesn't seem to move at all.

Is there any idea to push the installation forward? Internet access is OK, speed is 10Mbps minimum, all other pods install without any problems. More then 1 hour spent at this moment, I've tried to relaunch the installation - nothing helped at all

Comment: We use Cocoapods to install Realm all the time. Can you please clarify your question by including your podfile, version of cocoaPods (pod --version) as well as your version of Xcode. Also, why Realm 10.8.1? That's an older version - see the new versions here [Realm Releases](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/releases)

Comment: Well, the app is written on Objective C and 'pod update' shows 10.8.1 version only. Cocoapods are updated

Comment: Again, please update the question so we can assist you.